# One event doesn't trigger at all. But the next one does

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

Need some help with socket.io really can't find where is the problem. Im going to split it for your better understanding.

First of all here is my socketServer.js

```js
socket.on("start-game", (newQuiz) => {
    quiz = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newQuiz));
    console.log(quiz);
    console.log("Move players to game");
    console.log(game.pin);
    socket.to(game.pin).emit("move-to-game-page", game._id);
  });

  socket.on("question-preview", (cb) => {
    console.log("Received question-preview on the server");
    console.log(game.pin);
    cb();

    console.log("Emitting host-start-preview from the server");
    socket.to(game.pin).emit("host-start-preview");
  });

  socket.on("start-question-timer", (time, question, cb) => {
    // console.log(question)
    console.log("Send question " + question.questionIndex + " data to players");
    socket.to(game.pin).emit("host-start-question-timer", time, question);
    cb();
  });
```

Then is my Host(client). Who press the start button

```js
  const startGame = () => {
    socket.emit("start-game", quiz);
    socket.emit("question-preview", () => {
      startPreviewCountdown(5, currentQuestionIndex);
    });
    setStage("preview");
  };
```

And here is my problem this is my player code(client)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Setting up event listeners on client-side...");
    socket?.on("host-start-preview", () => {
      console.log("HOST STARTED PREVIEW");
      setIsPreviewScreen(true);
      setIsResultScreen(false);
      startPreviewCountdown(5);
    });

    console.log("DOESNT SHOW");
  }, [socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("host-start-question-timer", (time, question) => {
      console.log("HOST START QUESTION TIMER");
      setQuestionData(question.answerList);
      startQuestionCountdown(time);
      setAnswer((prevstate) => ({
        ...prevstate,
        questionIndex: question.questionIndex,
        answers: [],
        time: 0,
      }));
      setCorrectAnswerCount(question.correctAnswersCount);
    });
  }, [dispatch, socket]);
```

So the problem is I'm starting the game as host.
On my server I'm getting the console.log that I'm expecting

```js
Move players to game
5419
Received question-preview on the server
5419
Emitting host-start-preview from the serve
```

On my host everything works perfectly my setStage becomes preview I'm emitting the events all perfectly.

Now my player
The event with socket.on host-start-preview doesn't trigger.
And after my timer the "host-start-question-timer" triggers
Inside my

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ socket });
  }, [socket]);
```

I can see that I have the call-back for the host-start-preview.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: maybe the ? after socket: socket?.on("host-start-preview", () => {
      console.log("HOST STARTED PREVIEW");
      setIsPreviewScreen(true);
      setIsResultScreen(false);
      startPreviewCountdown(5);
    }

Answer (score 0):

socket?.on should maybe be "socket.on"

Comment: unfortunately no